# Layering (or nesting) multiple Bokeh transforms

Tags: python, data-visualization, bokeh

I need to dynamically layer (or "nest") multiple Bokeh transforms, most of which are CustomJSTransforms. Is there anyway to do that? 
Is there any way to use syntax like:
`Log10Transform(ThresholdTransform(column_name))`

or 
`LinearColorMapper(Log10Tranform(column_name))`

I'm currently using the 
`{'field':column_name, 'transform':Log10Transform}`
syntax which doesn't seem to allow for layering.

I could handle the layering of purely mathematical transforms by just writing a ton of hideous  transforms, but as far as I can tell there's no way for me to do the `ColorTransform(MathTransform(...))`.

Just in case it's relevant, I'm using Bokeh v 12.5, and do not have the ability to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

the `composite_transform()` calls `transforms` one by one:

```
from inspect import Signature, Parameter

def composite_transform(*transforms):
    def trans_func():
        transforms = arguments
        res = x
        for transform in transforms.values():
            res = transform.compute(res)
        return res

    def vtrans_func():
        transforms = arguments
        res = window.Array["from"](xs)
        for transform in transforms.values():
            res = transform.v_compute(res)
        return res

    parameters = [Parameter("T{:02d}".format(i), Parameter.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD, default=trans) 
                      for i, trans in enumerate(transforms)]
    trans_func.__signature__ = Signature(parameters=parameters)
    vtrans_func.__signature__ = Signature(parameters=parameters)
    trans = CustomJSTransform.from_py_func(trans_func, vtrans_func)
    return trans
```

Here is an example:

imports:

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, ColorBar, CustomJS
from bokeh.models.transforms import CustomJSTransform
from bokeh.transform import transform
from bokeh.models.mappers import LinearColorMapper
from bokeh.palettes import Viridis, Category10
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.layouts import row, column
output_notebook()
```

plotting:

```
x, y = np.random.normal(scale=0.2, size=(2, 500))
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))
fig = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=300)

def dummy(source=source):
    return 0

def vtrans_value(source=source):
    data = source.data
    return [(data.x[i]**2 + data.y[i]**2)**0.5 for i in range(len(data.x))]

def vtrans_size():
    return [10 * x for x in window.Array["from"](xs)]

value_transform = CustomJSTransform.from_py_func(dummy, vtrans_value)
mult_transform = CustomJSTransform.from_py_func(dummy, vtrans_size)
cmap_transform = LinearColorMapper(Viridis[256], low=0, high=0.6)
color_transform = composite_transform(value_transform, cmap_transform)
size_transform = composite_transform(value_transform, mult_transform)

c = fig.circle("x", "y", 
               fill_color=transform("x", color_transform), 
               size=transform("x", size_transform),
               line_color=None, source=source, alpha=1)

colorbar = ColorBar(color_mapper=cmap_transform, label_standoff=12, border_line_color=None, location=(0,0))
fig.add_layout(colorbar, "right")
show(fig)
```

the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton! This seems very promising. Unfortunately I'm stuck using python 2.7, so I don't have access to the inspect functions you used. Without those it fails with the following javascipt error: `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'arc' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The radius provided (-0.0103611) is negative.` Also, can you explain the `transforms=arguments` lines? Why does the transforms closure fail, and what is arguments?

Comment: bokeh converts `vtrans_func()` to javascript code, `arguments` is the same as `*args` in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to HYRY for their response. Unfortunately, I couldn't get that version to work for me. Here's my solution:

```
def CompositeTransform(*transforms):
   """Performs a series of bokeh transforms."""
   composite_transform_func = """
     res = x;
     for (i = 0; i < tlist.tags.length; i++) {
       trans = eval(tlist.tags[i]);
       res = trans.compute(res)
     }
     return res
   """

   composite_transform_v_func = """
     res = xs;
     for (i = 0; i < tlist.tags.length; i++) {
       trans = eval(tlist.tags[i]);
       res = trans.v_compute(res)
     }
     return res
   """
   arg_dict = dict([("t" + str(i), trans) for i, trans in enumerate(transforms)])
   arg_dict["tlist"] = TransformTag(
   tags=["t" + str(i) for i in range(len(transforms))])
   return CustomJSTransform(
       func=composite_transform_func,
       v_func=composite_transform_v_func,
       args=arg_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

CustomJSTransform doesnt have a .from_py_func() method anymore, so HYRY's answer doesn't work in any longer (in version 2.4.3 at least).

MHankin's answer didn't work either but only needed small changes to run in 2.4.3:

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Transform
from bokeh.transform import transform

def composite_transform(field_name: AnyStr, *transforms:Transform):
bokeh-transforms
    """Performs a series of bokeh transforms."""
    composite_transform_func = """
      let res = x;
      for (let i = 0; i < tlist.length; i++) {
        let trans = eval(tlist[i]);
        res = trans['transform'].compute(res)
      }
      return res
    """

    composite_transform_v_func = """
      let res = xs;
      for (let i = 0; i < tlist.length; i++) {
        let trans = eval(tlist[i]);
        res = trans['transform'].v_compute(res)
      }
      return res
    """
    arg_dict = dict([("t" + str(i), trans) for i, trans in enumerate(transforms)])
    arg_dict["tlist"] = ["t" + str(i) for i in range(len(transforms))]
    return transform(field_name, CustomJSTransform(
        func=composite_transform_func,
        v_func=composite_transform_v_func,
        args=arg_dict))
```